# Inform the user about the terms for using the Android app

Tags: android

I have never used Google store before to publish an app and I hope someone will advice me how can I manage the following problem.

I am implemnting an Android app to  display the bus location in my city in Google maps view based on Crowd sourcing. The data (lat, long, mac, speed, time, etc.) is being recorded in the background and transmitted to the server. The MAC address is used as identifier for the requester at the server side and I am storing it in the database tables  as long as the background tracking service runs.

To use the app, the user has to agree this term when installing the app.

my question: Can I manage this work with google store for example in the `Full description` area or some where els to get this confirmation from the users or I have to implement the installation process by myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of users who don't usually read the description, so it's not good to paste the terms in there.

The best way is to show the terms on the first launch of the application.